# How can I use awk to (sometimes) remove the first character of a column?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I run a command and pipe it through awk as below :

`mycommand |  awk '{print $1,tolower($3),$4}`

This gives me the following output:

```
fred.o: t .abcdefg 
fred.o: u .rstuvwxy 
fred.o: t .defghi 
fred.o: t .jklmnop 
fred.o: d abcdefg 
fred.o: d zyxwvuts
```

As you can see the sometimes the third column contains a leading "." but not always.

How can I modify my `awk` command to get rid of the leading "." in the third column if it exists ?  eg I would like my output to look like this :

```
fred.o: t abcdefg  
fred.o: u rstuvwxy  
fred.o: t defghi  
fred.o: t jklmnop  
fred.o: d abcdefg  
fred.o: d zyxwvuts
```

Answer (score 9):

```
mycommand | awk '{sub(/^\./, "", $4);print $1,tolower($3),$4}'
```

Comment: This works perfectly and is very elegant too. Thank you Nykakin for your very swift and very helpful response.

Comment: @signal11 If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the SE way of expressing thanks.